# Get data after using mysqli::store_result()

Tags: php, mysqli

I am selecting data from my database in the following way: As expected I get one row as result and want to extract the `lat` and `lon` data from it:

```
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT lat, lon FROM members WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";   
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

      if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
          logC("user exists");
          logC("extract lat, lon!");
        } 
      }
```

I tried using `$stmt->fetch()` and extracting it from the `$result` variable but without success. What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're expecting just one result:

```
  if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($lat, $lon);

    if(($result = $stmt->fetch()) == true){
      echo "'$lat' and '$lon'";
    } elseif($result == false) {
      echo 'db error';
    } else {
      echo 'no results'; // $result == null
    }


  }
```

If you have multiple rows, $stmt->fetch() will bind the next result to the same variables so you can do:

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
  echo $lat, $lon;
}
```

It is just 1 way of many.. just read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php).

Answer (score 0):

why don't you frame your query along with `user_id` and skip binding. Then you can directly execute your query and fetch result.

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT lat, lon FROM members WHERE id = '".$user_id."' LIMIT 1")
```